# Redirect to language specific domain - Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, redirection

I'm using Apache 2.4 to host those domains:

```
domena.pl/
domena.pl/ru
domena.pl/en
```

I need to redirect domena.com to domena.pl/en. Here's my htacces file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domena\.ru
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/pl$"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domena.pl/pl [R=303,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domena\.ru
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/$"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domena.ru/ru [R=303,NC,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.domena.pl|www.domena.ru)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domena.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^/*$ cached/index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add another rule as other are:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domena\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/$"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domena.pl/en [R=303,NC,L]
```

You need to add this rule before `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.domena.pl|www.domena.ru)$`to be triggered

Comment: Thank you but this didnt work.

Comment: You need to add the rule before `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.domena.pl|www.domena.ru)$`

Comment: Thank you, now it worked! However, I tried to move it to the real server, having such htacces file: http://pastie.org/private/wwk2xyyztbfg0nmq0sxxra. Now, I want to redirect `almacolor.com` to 1almacolor.com/en1. I tried this: http://pastie.org/private/ijpfzd1uvddteoltawpag but something is wrong, since it does not work. Could you please help?

Comment: Can you try (with the configuration you posted) if http://almacolor.com/ works, else if it doesn't, can you tell me what message you get, thanks